# Unexpected token export with ES2015 preset

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I have created a package for my Express application and am importing it, in the package I have:

```
'use strict';   
export default class BlogDatabase { ... }
```

In .babelrc, I have **presets: ["es2015"]** (works normally and I have seen several questions similar to mine, but the resolution was that they did not have presets for ES6, I do have them and it works for everything except import/export.)

But it still throws the following error saying that "export" is an unexpected token:

```
export
^^^^^^
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the transpiled script instead of the original? Also, what throws this error, babel, node, something else?